# Trouble with inserting specific xml nodes into a table

Tags: c#, xml

I am very new to xml and I am 95% done with my project for work, But when I try and do the last insert into a table it always duplicates my one value.

For example if I have transactions that needs to be inserted into the table and all the transactions are enclosed in a stage node. each stage has transactions.

Now when I insert stage 1 and it has 5 transactions it must take the id of stage 1 then when the insert is done it must then go to stage 2 and then insert 10 transactions.

My issue is when I insert the transactions it will only take the first stage id for all the trans inserts.

Here is my method how I am inserting the transactions

```
private List<XMLTransaction> GetAllTransForStage(List<XElement> allTransDetails, string path, int curStage, int nxtStage, int journeyEnd, int IDStage, int IDJourney, int IDDuty, int IDModule, string BoardingStages)
    {
        var end = nxtStage > 0 ? nxtStage : journeyEnd;
        var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
        List<XElement> StageRersult = GetTranseDetails(doc);
        var transForCurrentStage = StageRersult.Where(s => Int32.Parse(s.Attribute("Position").Value.ToString()) > curStage && Int32.Parse(s.Attribute("Position").Value.ToString()) < end).ToList();
        var transactions = new List<XMLTransaction>();


        string TripBal = "";
        string serial = "";
        int IDTranse = 0;
        int hexClassValue = 0;
        int second = 0;
        double seconds = 0;
        TimeSpan t;
        string formatedTime = "";
        string date = "";
        string issueDate = "";
        string issueTime = "";
        int stageno = 0;
        int HexClasValue = 0;
        int Fare = 0;

        DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();
        dt4.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[17] {
                new DataColumn("id_Trans",typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("id_Stage", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("id_Journey", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("id_Duty",typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("id_Module",typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("int2_BoardingStageID",typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("int2_AlightingStageID",typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("int2_Class",typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("int4_Revenue",typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("int4_NonRevenue",typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("int2_TicketCount",typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("int2_PassCount",typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("int2_Transfers",typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("dat_TransDate",typeof(DateTime)),
                new DataColumn("dat_TransTime",typeof(DateTime)),
                new DataColumn("str_SerialNumber",typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("int4_TripBal",typeof(int))
            });


        int batchID = Convert.ToInt32(dtImportDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
        XDocument xdoc3 = XDocument.Load(path);
        XDocument xdoc4 = XDocument.Load(path);
        //////////////
        string ConString = Settings.Default.ebusimporterConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
        {

            string sql = "SELECT TOP 1 id_Trans FROM Trans ORDER BY 1 DESC";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            try
            {
                con.Open();

                object val = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (val != null)
                {
                    IDTranse = Convert.ToInt32(val);
                    IDTranse = IDTranse + 1;
                }
                else if (val == null)
                {
                    IDTranse = Convert.ToInt32(val);
                    IDTranse = IDTranse + 1;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }


        foreach (var tran in transForCurrentStage)
        {


            string Hex = tran.Element("TicketType").Value.ToString();
            string stageN = tran.Element("StageNo").Value.ToString();
            string Issuetime = tran.Element("IssueTime").Value.ToString();
            string fares = tran.Element("Fare").Value.ToString();
            string Issuedate = tran.Element("IssueDate").Value.ToString();
            string TicketSerialNo = tran.Element("TicketSerialNo").Value.ToString();





            //  string TicketType = item.TicketType.ToString();

            hexClassValue = int.Parse(Hex, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            stageno = Int32.Parse(stageN);
            HexClasValue = hexClassValue;
            second = Int32.Parse(Issuetime);
            seconds = second;
            t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
            formatedTime = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}",
                      t.Hours,
                      t.Minutes,
                       t.Seconds);
            Fare = Int32.Parse(fares);
            string dateLength = Issuedate;

            if (dateLength.Length == 5 && HexClasValue == 17 || HexClasValue == 18 || HexClasValue == 33 || HexClasValue == 34 || HexClasValue == 65 || HexClasValue == 66)
            {
                date = "0" + Issuedate;
                issueDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dMMyy", null).ToString("yyyy-MM-d");
                issueTime = issueDate + " " + formatedTime;

                //Cash
                if (HexClasValue == 17 || HexClasValue == 18 || HexClasValue == 33 || HexClasValue == 34 || HexClasValue == 65 || HexClasValue == 66)
                {

                    dt4.Rows.Add(IDTranse, IDStage, IDJourney, IDDuty, IDModule, Convert.ToInt16(BoardingStages), Convert.ToInt16(stageN), Convert.ToInt16(HexClasValue), Fare, 0, 1, 0, 0, Convert.ToDateTime(issueDate), Convert.ToDateTime(issueTime), TicketSerialNo, Convert.ToInt32(0));
                    IDTranse++;

                }
            }

            if (dateLength.Length == 6 && HexClasValue == 17 || HexClasValue == 18 || HexClasValue == 33 || HexClasValue == 34 || HexClasValue == 65 || HexClasValue == 66)
            {
                date = Issuedate;
                issueDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dMMyy", null).ToString("yyyy-MM-d");
                issueTime = issueDate + " " + formatedTime;

                //Cash
                if (HexClasValue == 17 || HexClasValue == 18 || HexClasValue == 33 || HexClasValue == 34 || HexClasValue == 65 || HexClasValue == 66)
                {

                    dt4.Rows.Add(IDTranse, IDStage, IDJourney, IDDuty, IDModule, Convert.ToInt16(BoardingStages), Convert.ToInt16(stageN), Convert.ToInt16(HexClasValue), Fare, 0, 1, 0, 0, Convert.ToDateTime(issueDate), Convert.ToDateTime(issueTime), TicketSerialNo, Convert.ToInt32(0));
                    IDTranse++;

                }
            }
        }

        string ConnString4 = Settings.Default.ebusimporterConnectionString;
        if (HexClasValue == 11000)
        {

        }
        else if (dt4.Rows.Count != 0)
        {

            using (SqlConnection con4 = new SqlConnection(ConnString4))
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con4))
                {

                    //revenuebal  = 0 
                    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Trans";

                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("id_Trans", "id_Trans");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("id_Stage", "id_Stage");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("id_Journey", "id_Journey");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("id_Duty", "id_Duty");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("id_Module", "id_Module");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("int2_BoardingStageID", "int2_BoardingStageID");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("int2_AlightingStageID", "int2_AlightingStageID");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("int2_Class", "int2_Class");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("int4_Revenue", "int4_Revenue");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("int4_NonRevenue", "int4_NonRevenue");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("int2_TicketCount", "int2_TicketCount");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("int2_PassCount", "int2_PassCount");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("int2_Transfers", "int2_Transfers");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("dat_TransDate", "dat_TransDate");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("dat_TransTime", "dat_TransTime");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("str_SerialNumber", "str_SerialNumber");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("int4_TripBal", "int4_TripBal");

                    con4.Open();
                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt4);
                    con4.Close();

                }
            }
        }
        LogwriterSuccess("ImportTrans", path);

        return transactions;
    }
```

Comment: You should break the method down into smaller functions it will make it easier to read and probably help you pin point where your code is going wrong. A method should be no more than 4/5 lines (according to Uncle Bob)

Comment: If you can correct your code so that it's readable it will be easier to understand what you do, and also, if you can post a sample of your XML we can probably understand better the problem. because your description is not so clear reading it as it surely is to you when writing.

Comment: Even if there is a point, why you dont want to split this: Think of some parts in the code and what they are doing:
e.g:
1.right after object val = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
2.right after string ConnString4 = Settings.Default.ebusimporterConnectionString;
Think of writing a few lines less there.

Comment: You need t get the elements (or descendants) of the element 'tran'.  Can't help without seeing sample of XML.